# Find $(x_1,\dots,x_n) \in (\mathbb{R}_+^*)^n$ to minimize $\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_k\prod_{i=1}^{k}{(1 + x_i)}$ such that $\sum_{k=1}^{n}{x_k} = 1$

Tags: optimization

I want to find $(x_1,\dots,x_n) \in (\mathbb{R}_+^*)^n$ to minimize
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n}{x_k \prod_{i=1}^{k}{(1 + x_i)}} $$
with the following constraint $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}{x_k} = 1$.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: What tools do you have ? Do you know some differential geometry ?

Comment: I tried Lagrange multipliers but it seems to messy to be solved in that way. I think that the solution satisfies $x_1 \geq x_2 \geq \dots \geq x_n$, but I am not sure, still working on it...

Comment: differential geometry ? just a little. But any idea to help me to solve this it will be great ! ^^ I am ready to study diferential geometry if it is necessary to come close to a solution ^^

Comment: Have you solved the problem for $n=2$ or $n=3$?

Comment: Sure, for $n=2$ the solution is given by $(2/3,1/3)$, for $n=3$ I obtained a numerical solution only (0.54,0.26,0.20)

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer.

---

We could try Lagrange multipliers. Take the Lagrangian
$$\mathcal L (\textbf{x},\lambda) = \sum_{k=1}^n x_k \prod _{j=1}^k (1+x_j) + \lambda \left (\sum _{k=1}^n x_k -1\right ) =: f(\textbf{x}) + \lambda g(\textbf{x}). $$
Find the candidate solution(s) by finding stationary point(s) i.e $\nabla\mathcal L= 0$. Get a system
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}f = (2x_i+1)\prod _{j=1}^{i-1}(1+x_j) + \sum _{k=i+1}^n \prod_{j=1 \\ j\neq i}^{i+1} (1+x_j) = -\lambda $$
with $g(\textbf{x})=0$, where for $i=1$ the first additive is simply $2x_1+1$. Unsure how to solve this analytically.

Comment: Thank you, I already tried Lagrange multipliers but as I said it seems too messy to be solved in that way analytically.